# Show Client Script error using ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock only once, and stop showing it once the error is no longer valid

Tags: asp.net, html, alert

I am not a webdeveloper. But I need to develop 2-3 aspx pages.
I show error with

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "_Validation", "alert('Captcha Error!')", true);
```

It Works. But if user want to show aggreement on a new page and after goback this page. Captcha error shows again.

I want to show some errors with alert, but these errors show every time that go back to this page(maybe can say onload).

how should I do?

Comment: Please explain more, do you want to show the captcha error only once?

Comment: @HassanMokdad; and Yes, I want to show error only once.

Comment: Put it in a conditional block where you decide whether there is error or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After validating your captcha, you need to store in a session variable a boolean indicating that the captcha is validated. And then before registering your client script you can check to see if the captcha is validated or not.

Another method is to use cookies and client side validation, where after showing the message, and validating the captcha, you will store a variable in a client cookie to signal that your captcha is validated. And next time you will check against this cookie before showing the alert

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "_Validation", "alert('Captcha Error!')", true);
```